# Getting 403 error when GET has "http://" or "https://"

Tags: php, get, http-status-code-403

i seem to be getting a error.
When i submit a form or have a URL like this "https://example.com/video.php?var=http://test.com/video.mp4" i seem to get a 403 error. Even if i encode the url to look like this "http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Fvideo.mp4". It still won't work. What video.php should do is get the 'var' and embed the video. The code looks like this. It doesn't matter if the url is "http://" or "https://"

```
<?php
    $VideoSRC = $_GET['v'];
if($_GET['v']){
?>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='https://example.com/Secure/!/css/fullscreen.css'>
    <!--<video class="videoFullT" preload="none" controls src='<?php echo $VideoSRC; ?>'></video>-->
    <video class="videoFULLT" id="my-video_html5_api" class="vjs-tech" controls autoplay="" preload="auto" data-setup="{}" style="width:100%;height:100%" src="<?php echo $VideoSRC; ?>">
        <source src="<?php echo $VideoSRC; ?>" type="video/mp4">
        <p class="vjs-no-js">
            To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that
            <a href="http://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank">supports HTML5 video</a>
        </p>
    </video>
    <?php
    exit();
}

?>
<form action="" method="get">
Video URL: <input type="text" name="v" placeholder="http://example.com/video.mp4" size="30"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the 403 message?

Comment: can't see you'd end up with `var=whatever` in the url, because your form's submitted via POST, and would be submitted `v=whatever` in any case, if it was submitting via GET.

Comment: Sorry that's a mistake in the code when i put it on stackoverflow

Comment: Are you getting the 403 for your entire page, or are you seeing the 403 in the browsers console when it tries to load the video?

Comment: I am seeing the error in the entire page

Comment: And the page is loading without the url?

Comment: Yes the page is loading without the url

Comment: Well 403 is an access forbidden message, I suspect your server is configured to block things that look like the could be a cross site scripting attack (which your could would allow).

Comment: Would i have to contact my server providers, can someone move this to a chat, please.

Comment: Potentially, yes I would imagine so, unless there is more code you aren't showing there is nothing there that should cause a 403. Its worth noting you should not be blindly outputting request variables in your webpage without properly escaping them, as this allows malicious code to be injected.

Comment: @Technofrood Ok. Thank You